# Grab a List Item from the Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, web-controls, listitem

I have a `ListItem` in the `Master` page that I need to assign for it a new `css class`.

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li id="myLI" runat="server"></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

The first thing I tried was the following:

```
ListItem li = this.Master.FindControl("myLI");
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

Then:

```
ListItem li = (ListItem) this.Master.FindControl("myLI");
```

> Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

Then:

```
Control li = this.Master.FindControl("myLI");
```

but I didn't find any method to give it a new CSS class.

Sounds like I need to grab a `WebControl` rather than `Control`. Any Solution?

Comment: Have you tried HtmlGenericControl?

Comment: Yep, it's HtmlGenericControl. Reason you can't use ListItem is that you haven't defined your `ul` as a control. `<ul id="myList" runat="server">`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast it as an `HtmlGenericControl`, like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl li = (HtmlGenericControl)this.Master.FindControl("myLI");
```

The `HtmlGenericControl` has an `AttributeCollection` property that you can then use:

```
li.Attributes.Add("class", "myClass");
```

Comment: Correct, I saw this before and I probably used it before, but Visual Studio doesn't show it to me unless I import it. best answer in 8 min...

Comment: If you want you can add that to change/add/remove class we do the following `li.Attributes["class"] = "myClass";`